# Javascript code not triggered after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm trying to develop an interactive website and i got stuck at the point where a file should be added and executed.So i have the following code in the head page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.info').live("click",function()
        {
            if ($('#country span.selected').text().length == 0)
                alert("A company should be selected before continue!");
            else {
                $('.centered').hide();
                $('.waitimg').show();
                $.post('get_data.php',
                {
                    type :$(this).attr("id"),
                    company : $('#country span.selected').text(),
                    company_id : $('#country').attr("value"),
                    country :  $('#scountry span.selected').text(), 
                    industry: $('#industry span.selected').text()
                }, function(response)
                {
                    //$('#resultarea').fadeOut();
                    setTimeout("finishAjax('resultarea','"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
                }
                );
            } 
            return false;                    
        });

    });
```

and the callback:

```
function finishAjax(id, response) {
        $('#waitimg').hide();
         $.getScript("js/script.js");
        $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
        $('#'+id).fadeIn();
    }
```

which it should execute the script from js/script.js but it does not. Using the Firebug i can see that the file is loaded but at simple alert("hello world") in script.js is not fired. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` expects a *reference* to a function, not a string as first argument. Replace:

```
setTimeout("finishAjax('resultarea','"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
```

with:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    return finishAjax.apply(this, ['resultarea', escape(response)]);//call as though finishAjax was callback --> preserve context
    //or, if you don't care about the context:
    return finishAjax('resultarea', escape(response));
}, 400);
```

And you're done

Comment: @StackOverfolow: I'm not psychic, so I don't know what your page looks like, or what other code might be causing issues. [try setting up a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what you've tried

Comment: the response is ok , my problem is that the code in script.js is not executed at all.

Comment: Try adding a success callback to the `getScript` call, log a couple of things... but please, do set up a fiddle - _and check your console_ a reply like _"Tried, does not work"_ doesn't say much as to where the code fails

Comment: getScript works great as i tested with the Firebug , the file is loaded.

Comment: @StackOverfolow: just on a slightly pedantic note, but the JS of your site is packed with lines like `setTimeout("scanHTML5Videos()", 2000);`, please replace them with `setTimeout(scanHTML5Videos, 2000);`, and the fiddle is not correct (check the left side: framework mootools should be jQuery, so the code doesn't work there. Also: I see you're using version 1.7, so don't use the `.live` method, but use `.on` instead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21603/discussion-between-stack-overfolow-and-elias-van-ootegem)